# Rails sort association proxy after new object is build

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have two models,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, -> { order('post.id') }
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: user
end
```

For instance i'm having a `@user` and two `posts` associated. while doing `@user.posts`, the result be like.

```
 [
  [0] #<Post:0x0000000aa53a20> {
                   :id => 3,               
                :title => 'Hello World',
              :comment => 'Long text comes here'
  },
  [1] #<Post:0x0000000aa53a41> {
                   :id => 5,               
                :title => 'Hello World 2',
              :comment => 'Long text comes here too'
  }
]
```

Now, I'm building one more extra object by doing `@user.posts.build` and
that the below result of doing `@user.posts`

```
[
  [0] #<Post:0x0000000aa53a20> {
                   :id => 3,               
                :title => 'Hello World',
              :comment => 'Long text comes here'
  },
  [1] #<Post:0x0000000aa53a41> {
                   :id => 5,               
                :title => 'Hello World 2',
              :comment => 'Long text comes here too'
  },
 [2] #<Post:0x0000000aa53a50> {
                   :id => nil,               
                :title => nil,
              :comment => nil
  },
]
```

What i actually want is, to sort by object with nil first. The result should exactly look like,

```
[
  [0] #<Post:0x0000000aa53a50> {
                   :id => nil,               
                :title => nil,
              :comment => nil
  },
  [1] #<Post:0x0000000aa53a20> {
                   :id => 3,               
                :title => 'Hello World',
              :comment => 'Long text comes here'
  },
  [2] #<Post:0x0000000aa53a41> {
                   :id => 5,               
                :title => 'Hello World 2',
              :comment => 'Long text comes here too'
  }
]
```

It can also be done by an custom method to sort by looping through each object. But don't want to write another method. The result should in Association Proxy and not an Array

Is it possible to achieve it in association proxy itself?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, you have the `@posts` variable where it contains the `nil` item.

```
@posts.sort{|i,j| i.id && j.id ? i <=> j : j.id ? -1 : 1 }

result => [nil, 3, 5]
```